# Trying to keep tutorial

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt

I'm trying to keep the tutorial simpleMaps of GWT on gwt-maps3 library but when launch  the apps show the next error on brows:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:406)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.google.gwt.maps.client.MapOptions.<init>(MapOptions.java:40)
at com.map.juan.client.SimpleMap.onModuleLoad(SimpleMap.java:18)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.google.gwt.maps.client.impl.MapOptionsImpl' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.create(GWT.java:57)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:85)
at com.google.gwt.maps.client.impl.MapOptionsImpl.<clinit>(MapOptionsImpl.java:31)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
at com.google.gwt.jsio.rebind.JSWrapperGenerator.generate(JSWrapperGenerator.java:276)
at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:657)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ShellModuleSpaceHost.rebind(ShellModuleSpaceHost.java:141)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:595)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:465)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
... 14 more
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks

added .java

```
public class SimpleMap implements EntryPoint 
{
private MapWidget mapWidget;

// GWT module entry point method.
public void onModuleLoad() 
{
    final MapOptions options = new MapOptions();
    // Zoom level. Required
    options.setZoom(8);
    // Open a map centered on Cawker City, KS USA. Required
    options.setCenter(new LatLng(39.509, -98.434));
    // Map type. Required.
    options.setMapTypeId(new MapTypeId().getRoadmap());

    // Enable maps drag feature. Disabled by default.
    options.setDraggable(true);
    // Enable and add default navigation control. Disabled by default.
    options.setNavigationControl(true);
    // Enable and add map type control. Disabled by default.
    options.setMapTypeControl(true);
    mapWidget = new MapWidget(options);
    mapWidget.setSize("800px", "600px");

    // Add the map to the HTML host page
    RootPanel.get("mapsTutorial").add(mapWidget);
}
```

added .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.0//EN"
"http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-   module.dtd">
<module rename-to='simplemap'>
<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>

<!-- Other module inherits                                      -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.maps.Maps' />    
<!-- <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> -->
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps? gwt=1&amp;file=api&amp;v=2.148" />
<!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
<entry-point class='com.map.juan.client.SimpleMap'/>

<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
<source path='client'/>
<source path='shared'/>

</module>
```

Comment: The error message is quite explicit: `Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected`. Unfortunately it is also highly dependent on your code, which you didn't post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is that since GWT 2.2 `JClassType` was converted to interface instead of abstract class. In your case you are using some library which have been compiled with GWT 2.1 in project which is using GWT 2.5. That's why you are getting this error.

To solve this problem you have two options:

1. Find sources of gwt-map3, and build it manually with GWT 2.5 SDK
2. Convert your project to use GWT 2.1 SDK